# SSH-сервер на Windows

Tags: windows, ssh

Можно ли организовать SSH сервер на Windows-машине? Будет ли там работать mc (midnight commander)?

Comment: Можно (какой вопрос - такой ответ)

Comment: Что надо было сделать? Спросить, как конкретно поступить? Разве это не было понятно, из самой сути вопроса, или вам дедукция отказала? Вам надо челом бить с покаянием, не корысти ради, а токмо волею информации датити? Не нужны мне "вАШИ" ответы. Оставьте при себе свои скабрезные отписки, умник.

Comment: ну, во-первых, спросить как и что установить или настроить для этого
а, во-вторых, по вашему вопросу тысячи готовых ответов дает гугл и яндекс... даже в похожих формулировках.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен SSH-клиент, то весьма удобно пользоваться [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Если вам нужен SSH-сервер, то вариантов достаточно много, например, [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/). Чтобы начать работать, просто установите обе программы и убедитесь, что брэндмауэр не закрывает 22 порт.

Comment: Спасибо. 
Меня интересует, конечно же, сервер. Сам сервер без менеджера mc не нужен. Но Миднайт Коммандер - это всё-таки UNIX-овая утилита. Поэтому скорее не в возможности создания SSH-сервера под Windows, а возможности запуская на нем удаленными клиентами mc или аналога. Будет ли такая возможность?

Comment: Метаморфозы... Сначала ssh, потом sshd, теперь mc. "А нельзя ли зачитать весь список?". Ну а насчёт mc -- посмотрите порты mc под cygwin. (Там вроде и sshd был)

Comment: Не уверен, но, скорее всего, работать не будет, хотя встречаются порты [Midnight Commander](http://www.siegward-jaekel.de/mc-gb.html) под Windows.

Comment: В списке пакетов на cygwin.com этот самый "кошмар командер" есть.